# How to pass options to capifony php command

Tags: php, symfony, capifony

To deploy one of my site I'm using the excelent tool called: http://capifony.org/ which is very handy, but today a composer update throws the error very similar to this: http://tech.enekochan.com/2013/12/16/fix-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-x-bytes-with-composer-update/.

My question is how can I pass mentioned option (`-d memory_limit=-1`) to php console in capifony scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Capifony site makes mention of [how to set which PHP binary is run](http://capifony.org/reference/symfony.html).

```
All symfony tasks (both symfony 1.x and Symfony2) run using the 
default php binary on the production server. You can change this via:

set :php_bin, "/path/to/php"
```

Try setting the string to `"/usr/bin/env php -d memory_limit=-1"`. The /usr/bin/env part is a Linux tool that will search the PATH for the given program, to avoid having to 'hard-code' the full path of the program into place.